# What is the meaning of command line options for python from the windows command prompt (example: -i, -m)

Tags: python, tkinter

When running python scripts from the command line, sometimes one has to use options like:

```
script.py
python script.py
python -m script.py
python -i script.py
```

What do these options do? Where can I find a full list of these options?

I'm asking because I wrote a gui using tkinter, and when I run it using either of the first two methods above I get an ImportError for tkinter, but the -i option works fine. Can I write a python script that defaults to some option (-i) when it is run?

EDIT: Here is the traceback regarding my ImporError:
it gives the file name and then:

```
    import tkinter
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I am using python 3.5.2, and this error doesn't appear if I use

```
python -i script.py
```

Comment: try `python --help`

Comment: if you have `ImportError` the add full error message (traceback) in question. Resolving problem with `ImportError` can be more usefull for you then information about options. Maybe you have different problem - ie. if you use Python2 then you have to import `Tkinter` instead of `tkinter`

Comment: BTW: `-i` means `interactive mode` also called `Python Shell` and normally is useless for running program.

Comment: if you have problem `ImportError` then you have some problem with installed modules, or paths to this modules. Maybe `Python Shell` adds path to `tkinter`. You can try script with `import sys ; print('\n'.join(sys.path))` to see all paths when you run with `-i` and without `-i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all the python command flags and what they do by typing

```
python --help
```

In the case of tkinter, you need to run with the `-i` flag because it will run in "interactive mode". This allows the windowed application to launch. The help says it best

> -i : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
>   if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x

Meanwhile `-m` launches a module as if it were a script.

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

Comment: I don't quite understand the phrase "in the case of tkinter, you need to run with the `-i` flag". You only need the `-i` flag if you want the interactive behavior. Even then, it's not going to work like you expect. `-i` is relatively useless with tkinter.